# BB 10 cascades maps

Tags: maps, blackberry-10

I have been looking at the samples for BB10 maps but I am just not really understanding it.  Does anyone have a link or a basic tutorial how I can get a default map to display on the device.  Nothing fancy, just a simple map or a link to "bb 10 maps" for dummies or something.

I would like to invoke a simple map using.  So i found a simple mapview that looks like it will work.  However, after playing around i don't think my ide like the import line for the maps.  If i take everything off the page and just put a label and comment out the import line, the page displays with just a label, once i add the import line, it doesn't work.  The page won't display.

so for example.  in my maps.qml page, if i export comment out the mapview and the mapview container then the page will display.  If i uncomment them it doesn't display.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
//    import bb.cascades.mapview 1.0

Page {
id: root
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {
    }
    ActivityIndicator {
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
    }
    Label {
        text: qsTr("This is where the lable is")
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
    }
    /*
    MapView {
        id: myMap
        longitude: -79.4042
        latitude: 43.6481
        altitude: 1800.0
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        onCreationCompleted: {
            myMap.setRenderEngine("RenderEngine3D")
        }
    }*/
}
}
```

Interesting enough, within my map.qml file it, when i go to the design view it says:
"problem leading qml file: 2:1 module "bb.cascades.mapview" is not installed"

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/mapview

Comment: Have you tried updating your OS and sdk?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use WebView { }
2. Reffer sample from following link

https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/webmapview

Answer (score 0):

You must chance the library from "import bb.cascades.mapview 1.0" 1.0 to "import bb.cascades.maps"

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
[Cascades Samples - Mapview](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/mapview)